# UpdatePanel Not Working Unless AutoPostBack Is True on DDL

Tags: c#, drop-down-menu, updatepanel, autopostback

I am having issues being able to update a gridview in an updatepanel with a DDL without updating the entire page. It won't work at all if `AutoPostBack` on the DDL is set to false and when I set it to true I believe it's updating.

```
if (page.ispostback)
{
    label.text="posted back"
}
else
{
    label1.text="not posted back"
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will get into page_load event event if it is ajax call. It should not send ajax call if AutoPostBack is false that is how dropdown is supposed to behave.